# Find function to find multiple strings

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with a couple possible strings, and I want to know in which row they're.

```
Dim lx As Integer
Dim FoundExec As Range
With Worksheets("Load " & LoadNr(1)).Range("G10:G26")
    Set FoundExec = .Find("Exec", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not FoundExec Is Nothing Then
        Dim FirstLoadAddress As String
        FirstLoadAddress = FoundExec.Address
        Do
            lx = FoundExec.Row
            Set FoundExec = .FindNext(FoundExec)

            'Code...

            Loop While FoundExec.Address <> FirstLoadAddress
    End If
End With
```

This works for me as it's supposed to, but I want also to find the values "OVS", "OV" and "OS", as the same code is to follow after those inputs.

I treid

```
Dim lx As Integer
Dim FoundExec As Range
Dim FoundOVS As Range
Dim FoundOV As Range
Dim FoundOS As Range
Dim AllOSS As Range

With Worksheets("Load " & LoadNr(1)).Range("G10:G26")
    Set FoundExec = .Find("Exec", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set FoundOVS = .Find("OVS", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set FoundOV = .Find("OV", LookIn:=xlValues)
    Set FoundOS = .Find("OS", LookIn:=xlValues)

    Set AllOSS = Application.Union(FoundExec, FoundOVS, FoundOV, FoundOS)
    If Not AllOSS Is Nothing Then
        Dim FirstLoadAddress As String

        'Code...

        FirstLoadAddress = AllOSS.Address
        Do
            lx = AllOSS .Row
            Set AllOSS = .FindNext(AllOSS)
            Loop While AllOSS.Address <> FirstLoadAddress
    End If
End With
```

But that turns in ongoing loop.

Is there a way to do that quickly? and why turns the second in ongoing loop?

Comment: The problem seems to be that you cannot `.Union` multiple searches and then do a `.FindNext` on it.  Check your code with a `Debug.Print AllOSS.Address` just after the `Do` then you'll understand why `Do Loop` will never exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all those Finds, Find is very, very inefficient...

Do like this:

```
With Worksheets("Load " & LoadNr(1)).Range("G10:G26")
 nr = .Rows.Count
 For r = 1 To nr
  If InStr("#Exec#OVS#OV#OS#", .Cells(r, 1) & "#") > 0 Then
   ' do whatever you need to do
  End If
 Next
End With
```

Even application.match is much more efficient than .Find

Comment: hehe...with 4 .FINDS? That's what you think try it, time it, and then talk....I did it and is much faster.... much, much faster... :) (and by the way what do you think .FIND is doing?)

Comment: **+1**       nice way of implementing the **OR**

Comment: It is not coded in VBA for sure...  Even if this is quicker, there is a slight chance it does it like this.

Comment: Again, the only thing I can say to you is to time it and than talk....but with 4 FINDS, will be, probably, 3 to 4 times slower :)

Comment: @CRondao, I do not say the contrary, I am just referring to your `[...](and by the way what do you think .FIND is doing?)`

Comment: Ok, no problem... :) But it is real, I dont know why but FIND is incredibly slow...I try it with application match and match is 3 times faster

Comment: Maybe because of the multiple optional features - _expression.Find(What, After, LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, SearchDirection, MatchCase, MatchByte, SearchFormat)_.  If you don't need all that, it's probably better to use another method :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, didn't no all of that. works great.
Although I had to change the if to '>=2' to prevent firing on empty cells.